# Google Sheets conditional formatting if a row title is in capital letters

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

My spreadsheet has a column of titles in column A (starting at row 22) with data values across the rows.
The title column has conditional formatting to change the color based upon the titles either starting with the word Crit or the title being uppercase, or both.

```
=IFERROR(FIND("Crit",A22),0)>0
```

---

```
=AND(EXACT(A22,Upper(A22)),LEN(A22)>0)
```

---

```
=AND(EXACT(A22,Upper(A22)),NOT(ISBLANK(A22)),IFERROR(FIND("CRIT",A22),0)>0)
```

How do I extend these formulas to apply to the entire row? So that entire rows are formatted the same way as their title in column A.

EDIT:
I have achieved this on my own, these were my solutions

```
=FIND("CRIT",$A22)
```

---

```
=FIND("Crit",$A22)
```

Those formulas can format the rows which start with CRIT or Crit in their title.

```
=AND(EXACT(UPPER($A22),$A22),NOT(ISBLANK($A22)))
```

And this formula works to format the uppercase titled rows and NOT label the blank rows.

Comment: @player0 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BsVfKgAUBYxX01XQi0DTqmSxCTmeZMGUl8MFMj3TbTo/edit#gid=1111103499

Comment: sheet is private

Answer (score 1):

try to apply it to the whole range instead of just A22

[image]

---

- green: `=REGEXMATCH($A22, "^Crit|^Crit.*")`
- yellow: `=REGEXMATCH($A22, "^CRIT|^CRIT [A-Z0-9]+$")`
- red: `=REGEXMATCH($A22, "^[A-Z0-9 ]+$")`

  [image: 5]